# Swift 3 - How do you initialise a multi-dimensional string array?

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

If I want to create a four dimensional string array I can type:

```
var array4 = [[[[String]]]]()
```

If I want to initialise a single dimensional array I can use:

```
var array1 = [String](repeating: nil, count 10)
```

So how do I initialise a four dimensional string array?

```
var array4 = [[[[String]]]](repeating: nil, count: 10)
```

Doesn't work and gives an "Expression type is ambiguous" error.

Comment: `var array1 = [String](repeating: nil, count 10)` doesn't compile. If you want to initialise the elements to `nil`, you need to have an array of *optionals*. But really you should be asking yourself whether an array of arrays of arrays of arrays is a suitable data structure for what you want to do. I suspect it isn't.

Comment: Keep in mind here that `[[[[String]]]]` is not a multidimensional array. It's a nested array. This matters because (a) modifying it can be incredibly expensive, and (b) each "row" (however you want to think about that in 4 dimensions) can be a different length.

Comment: Have rewritten this as a flat array for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong your declaration of `array1` will also give you error.

```
var array1 = [String](repeating: nil, count: 10) //This will not compile
```

Will also give you error

> Expression type '[String]' is ambiguous without more context"

Because you cannot set `nil` value to `String` you can set it `String?`, So you need to declare array with type `[String?]`.

```
var array1 = [String?](repeating: nil, count: 10) //This will compile
```

Same goes for `array4`. You can declare array4 like this way

```
var array4 = [[[[String]]]?](repeating: nil, count: 10) //With nil objects
```

**Or**

```
var array4 = [[[[String]]]](repeating: [], count: 10) //With empty array objects
```

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you want to actually do is declare a 4D array of a specified size, and then fill it by referring to the indices `a[0][1][0][1] = "something"`.

Let's suppose for the sake of example that you want a string at each corner of a hypercube (the only "concrete" example I can think of off the top of my head for a 4D array is 4D geometry). Then the vertex indices are going to be
[0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1]
...
[1,1,1,0]
[1,1,1,1]
- 16 in total. Long-hand (possible for length = 2) we have:

```
var a: [[[[String]]]]
a = [
        [
            [
                ["?", "?"], ["?", "?"]
            ],
            [
                ["?", "?"], ["?", "?"]
            ],
        ],
        [
            [
                ["?", "?"], ["?", "?"]
            ],
            [
                ["?", "?"], ["?", "?"]
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

Now, we notice that each dimension is just a copy of the previous dimension n times (2 in this case), so to do it generically let's define:

```
func arrayOf<T>(el: T, count: Int) -> [T] {
    return [T](repeatElement(el, count: count))
}
```

It would be lovely to use recursion with a function like:

```
// func arrayOfArrays<T>(el: T, count: Int, depth: Int) -> ??? {
//     if depth == 1 { return arrayOf(el: el, count: count) }
//     return arrayOf(el: arrayOfArrays(el: el, count: count, depth: depth - 1), count: count)
// }
// a1:[[[[String]]]] = arrayOfArrays(el:"?", count: 2, depth: 4)
```

but what does it return? Generics can't cope with this, so we have to do it longhand:

```
var a1: [[[[String]]]]

a1 = arrayOf(el: arrayOf(el: arrayOf(el: arrayOf(el: "?", count: 2), count: 2), count: 2), count: 2)

a1[0][0][0][0] // "?" as expected
a1[1][1][1][1] = "!?"
a1[1][1][1][1] // "!?" as required
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typealias TwoDimensionArray<T> = [Array<T>]
typealias ThreeDimensionArray<T> = [TwoDimensionArray<T>]
typealias FourDimensionArray<T> = [ThreeDimensionArray<T>]

var array4 = FourDimensionArray<String>.init(repeating: [], count: 10)

print(array4) // [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: You seem to be seeding the previous array inside the next - is that correct?